# A question about the linearity of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ and $Y$ be random variables. I know that:
\begin{equation}\label{aaa}\tag{I}
E\left[\sum_{j=1}^n  X_j \Bigg |  Y \right]=\sum_{j=1}^n E\left[ X_j \Big |  Y \right] 
\end{equation}

Now, suppose that $Y$ takes values $1,2, 3,...$.

How to prove the following?
$$E\left[\sum_{j=1}^Y  X_j \Bigg |  Y \right]=\sum_{j=1}^Y E\left[ X_j \Big |  Y \right] $$

The conditional expectation is with respect to $\sigma(Y)$, the sigma algebra generated by the discrete random variable $Y$.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, the conditioning is with respect to a sub $\sigma$ field, in this case $\sigma(Y)$ regardless. Perhaps you mean with respect to the $\sigma$ field generated by $\{\omega | Y(\omega) = k \}$? (In which case the formula holds true, of course.)

Comment: I didn't really understand the difference. $Y$ is a discrete variable taking values in natural numbers. Conditional expecation is with respect to sigma-algebra generated by $Y$: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312474/what-is-it-meant-with-the-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-random-variable

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the definition of conditional expectation. The range of $Y$ is somewhat irrelevant. But there is a big difference between conditioning on $\sigma(Y)$ and conditioning on $\sigma([Y=k])$.

Comment: Oh yes. I understood your question. In this case, I want to demonstrate that the formula holds for $\sigma(Y)$. I believe that if this holds, then it holds for $\sigma([Y=k])$

Comment: Well, linearity is almost immediate from the definition, and is true for conditioning on any sub $\sigma$ field.

Comment: My apologies, I missed the $Y$ upper bound in the lower expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for any random variable $Y$ with support in $\mathbb{N}$, we have that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^Y X_j=\sum_{j\geqslant 1}X_j \mathbf{1}_{\{Y\geqslant j\}}\tag1
$$
Therefore if the $X_k$ are integrable and $Y$ is bounded then $\sum_{j=1}^Y X_j$ is integrable, and so it conditional expectation, respect to $Y$, exists and is almost sure finite, and we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^Y X_j\middle|Y\right]&\overset{(1)}{=}\operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{j\geqslant 1} X_j\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\geqslant j\}}\middle|Y\right]\\
&=\sum_{j\geqslant 1}\operatorname{E}[X_j\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\geqslant j\}}|Y]\\
&=\sum_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\geqslant j\}}\operatorname{E}[X_j|Y]\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^Y \operatorname{E}[X_j|Y]
\end{align*}
$$

where the second equality follows using the dominated convergence theorem and the third because the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\geqslant j\}}$ is $\sigma (Y)$-measurable for each $j$.

Comment: Math is beautiful. I am delighted with her. Thank you very much!